# Playing short animation xCode iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, video, animation

thanks for all your advice I took out of this forum over the last weeks.

Now I've a problem where I would need your help:

I want to show a series of short animations (5 animations, 10 sec each) on the iPhone. The animation would loop but the code will decide if the current loop is repeated or another loop will be started (Laughing face, shouting face, crying face etc.).

I am a little concerned that if I would design this animation with single images to be played the size of the app would explode. So video came to my mind. On the other hand we need to overlay the animation with changing images, so video could be a kind of hassle.

Any ideas about the best way to go?

Thanx for all your advice.

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 5 animations of 10 seconds each, i would suggest using single images. And you can use UIImageView's inbuilt animation with repeat count. It will be very easy to code.

Only make sure not to use `[UIImage imageNamed:@""]` while creating image arrays as you might have many images. This method creates an autorelease object and you wouldn't want many such objects hanging around in your app.

Comment: Thanks! This was the info I was looking for!!